# Cell below animatedly resized cell jumps in a weird way

Tags: swift, animation, tableview

I'm trying to make an expandable cell which height is defined by a constraint inside it called `backHighlightHeight`. But I'm getting this

[image]

I've tried to build this is many ways but the way I think should work as expected is like this:

`didSelectRowAt`:

```
if let tappedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? WorkoutCell {
    if let index = self.collapsedIndexPaths.firstIndex(of: indexPath) {
        self.collapsedIndexPaths.remove(at: index)
        tappedCell.showSets(true)
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    } else {
        self.collapsedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
        tappedCell.showSets(false)
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Inside `WorkoutCell`:

```
func showSets(_ show: Bool) {
    if show {
        backHighlightHeight.constant = 200
    } else if !show {
        backHighlightHeight.constant = 64
    }
}
```

And inside the cell's method called in `cellForRow` there's the logic to correctly set the height as well.

Comment: Which view are you setting the height constraints on for the cell?

Comment: It’s the view that defines its height (it has a height constraint and it’s connected to the top and bottom of the ContentView). I don’t think the issue is inside the cell but a reloading this with the tableView which I can’t figure out. The duplication that happens when expanding the cell is really weird